# how to check word is or not full filled in this div using javascript 

Tags: javascript

this is my code:

```
<div id="a" style="position:absolute;top:300px;width:100px;height:100px;background:red;color:black;word-wrap:break-word;">
    <div id='a2' contenteditable=true ></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    String.prototype.repeat = function(n) {
        return new Array(1 + parseInt(n, 10)).join(this);
    }

    var s=$('#a').width()/4*$('#a').height()/19;
    $('#a2').html('&nbsp;'.repeat($('#a').width()/4*parseInt($('#a').height()/19)))

    $('#a2').click(function(){
        alert('sss')
    })

</script>
```

and i fill space full in the div , but later , i will fill chinese word and english word in the div , and chinese word and english word has different length from each other,

so how to check the the word is or not full filled in the div ,

and not more(overflow) or less ,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You will either have to use a bitmap font (for each letter an image with the same size) or a fixed width font (monospaced font, e.g. Courier New and Lucida Console).

Or you can cut the text by setting `overflow:hidden` property for the div.